# How to stop the counting process for the if loop in my code?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to stop the counting process for `y` after it first time meet the condition of `y < 0` for each `i` in the `for loop`. Which means, the counting process for `x` will still continue as long as `x > 0` (condition stated in the `while loop`).

I had tried to do something which is `if (y < 0 & (y - 120*(16/81)*time + (z-2)) > 0 & z > 2)`, it make sense for me but the result doesn't make sense because after I run the code, `count_x` is around 100 (make sense) but `count_y` is more than 1000 which doesn't make sense since the `for loop` is only from `1:1000`.

```
count_x <- 0
count_y <- 0

for (i in 1:1000){
  x <- 25
  y <- 25
  t <- 0
  while ((x > 0 | y > 0) & t < 100){
    time <- rexp(1,100)
    u <- runif(1,0,1)
    z <- 4/((1-u)^0.2) - 4
    if (z < 2){
      x <- x + 110*(65/81)*time - z
    } else {
      y <- y + 120*(16/81)*time - (z-2)
      x <- x + 110*(65/81)*time - 2
    }
    t <- t + time
    if (x < 0){
      count_x <- count_x + 1
    }
    if (y < 0 & (y - 120*(16/81)*time + (z-2)) > 0 & z > 2){
      count_y <- count_y + 1
    }    
  }
}
```

For example, during the 1st iteration `i=1`, the `while loop` will start and run the code inside the loop. So what I want to do is:

When `y` first time reach negative value in the first iteration, it will update the `count_y` by one, then the whole `if loop` for the counting process of `y` will stop doing any thing even though the `while loop` is still continue to run since the `if loop` for counting process of `x` might not reach it first negative value yet (the condition for the `while loop` still satisfied if `t` is still smaller than 100), so the `while loop` need to be continue without touching last inner `if loop` until either `t>100` first or `x` first time reach its negative value. Once, the conditions for `while loop` do not satisfied, then only go for the 2nd iteration `i=2`.

Same thing goes to `x`, the counting process for `x` will stop doing anything once `x` first time become a negative value but the `while loop` will continue working as long as the condition for the `while loop` still satisfied.

So, there will only be one time update for either `x` or `y` for each iteration (so maximum for `y` should be 1000 since we have 1000 iteration, although unlikely to reach 1000) since the counting process for both `x` and `y` will stop once it reaches the first negative value.

I'm thinking to add `break` function into it but not sure where should I add.

Comment: edited the question, forgot to attach my code

Comment: It hard to understand why you are using a for loop as the use of i is not used for iteration in your loop

Comment: The for loop is used to check in 1000 times, how many times the `x` and `y` will be `<0` first and how many times `t` will be greater than 100 first. Which is the condition in `while loop`

Comment: Are you saying that y should be counted the first time it crosses zero during the while loop on the i iteration and should not be counted thereafter?

Comment: Ya, thats what I mean. But it will start counting again when the 2nd iteration start. Same thing goes to `x` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code. The y counter, to me at least, seems like it is correct. The reason why y is larger is two-fold. Firstly, even though the outer `for` loop is only 1000, the inner `while` loop could potentially run for more than a 100 at each i iteration. Secondly, it appears that y goes below 0 before x does, hence why the x counter is smaller.

I've modified your code to include a counter that counts how many `while` iterations occur, and two variables that store the values of `x` and `y` respectively, the first time that `y` goes below zero.

```r
count_x <- 0
count_y <- 0
while_count <- 0
store_x <- 0
store_y <- 0

a <- 1
b <- 1

for (i in 1:1000){
  x <- 25
  y <- 25
  t <- 0
  count_while <- 0
  while ((x > 0 | y > 0) & t < 100){
    time <- rexp(1,100)
    u <- runif(1,0,1)
    z <- 4/((1-u)^0.2) - 4
    if (z < 2){
      x <- x + 110*(65/81)*time - z
    } else {
      y <- y + 120*(16/81)*time - (z-2)
      x <- x + 110*(65/81)*time - 2
    }
    t <- t + time
    if (x < 0){
      count_x <- count_x + 1
    }
    if (y < 0 & (y - 120*(16/81)*time + (z-2)) > 0 & z > 2){
      count_y <- count_y + 1
      store_y[a] <- y
      store_x[a] <- x
      a <- a + 1
    }
    if (y > 0){
      count_while <- count_while + 1
    }
  }
  while_count[b] <- count_while
  b <- b + 1
}
```

Checking the averages shows that x is almost exclusively greater than zero the first time y goes below zero. The while loop averages 163 iterations.

```r
mean(store_x)
[1] 38.90333
mean(store_y)
[1] -2.035492
mean(while_count)
[1] 163.052
which(store_x < 0)
[1] 656
```

So, your counter seems correct to me, x is low simply because it rarely goes below zero. In fact, run the loop for just one iteration by setting `for (i in 1:1)` and run it several time, you'll find that your `count_x` rarely goes above zero, despite the `while` loop iterating over a 100 times. On the other hand, `y` goes below zero at least once on each `i` iteration.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Mr.Rlover, thanks for your solution! Appreciated! However, I think I'm not clear enough what I want in my question, so I had edited my question again by adding example, hope can get some advise from you again! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We will create variables for both x and y that will store and track when both cross zero on each i iteration. First we will check if x or y is zero and if `neg` is of class `NULL`. If so, then this is the first negative. We store `x_0` or `y_0` as 1. Then when counting, we check if `x_0` or `y_0` is equal to one and if `neg` is `NULL`. Then we will add to the counter and record the first negative. Thereafter, the condition evaluates to `FALSE`.

```r
count_x <- 0
count_y <- 0
while_x <- 0
while_y <- 0

for (i in 1:1000){
  x <- 25
  y <- 25
  t <- 0
  x_0 <- 0
  y_0 <- 0
  neg <- NULL
  neg_x <- NULL
  while ((x > 0 | y > 0) & t < 100){
    time <- rexp(1,100)
    u <- runif(1,0,1)
    z <- 4/((1-u)^0.2) - 4
    if (z < 2){
      x <- x + 110*(65/81)*time - z
      if (x < 0 & is.null(neg_x)){
        x_0 <- 1
      }
    } else {
      y <- y + 120*(16/81)*time - (z-2)
      x <- x + 110*(65/81)*time - 2
      if (x < 0 & is.null(neg_x)){
        x_0 <- 1
      }
      if (y < 0 & is.null(neg)) {
        y_0 <- 1
      }
    }
    t <- t + time

    if (x_0 == 1 & is.null(neg_x)){
      count_x <- count_x + 1
      neg_x <- "First Negative"
      x_0 <- x_0 + 1
    }
    if (y_0 == 1 & is.null(neg)){
      count_y <- count_y + 1
      neg <- "first negative"
      y_0 <- y_0 + 1
    }
  }
}
```

You can also place a counter outside the while loop. If x or y is less than 0, add to the counter. This is probably a better solution. The condition will evaluate regardless of *when* x or y cross below zero, as long as it went below zero, it will evaluate to `TRUE`

```r
count_x <- 0
count_y <- 0

for (i in 1:1000){
  x <- 25
  y <- 25
  t <- 0
  while ((x > 0 | y > 0) & t < 100){
    time <- rexp(1,100)
    u <- runif(1,0,1)
    z <- 4/((1-u)^0.2) - 4
    if (z < 2){
      x <- x + 110*(65/81)*time - z
    } else {
      y <- y + 120*(16/81)*time - (z-2)
      x <- x + 110*(65/81)*time - 2
    }
    t <- t + time
  }
  if(x < 0) {
    count_x <- count_x + 1
  }
  if(y < 0){
    count_y <- count_y + 1
  }
}
```

For me, `count_y` comes out at a 1000 in both cases. This confirms what I said previously, y goes below zero at each `while` iteration.